# Model return null when Post action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Below is my ViewModel

Please check my below view code and help me...

I have tried but not find root cause for null model returning.tried with bind and all type of methods.

```
public class PropertyDetailsViewModel
{
    public Property Propertys { get; set; }
    public PropertyContentBasic ContentBasic { get; set; }
    public List<ProviderPropertyModel> ProviderPropertyModelList { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> ProviderList { get; set; }
    public long NewProvider { get; set; }
}
```

when I call Post action methods this object comes with null value. only NewProvider value  return.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2l2zM.png)

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Your viewmodel property should match with object property sent from client side